# How to determine the setTimeout function while internet slow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, deep-linking

I try to redirect the user to app if they have installed in their device else redirects them to app download page (iTunes).

This below script working fine, but sometimes my internet getting slow both appUrl and webUrl has been fired. How to manage this problem???

```
if (IOSSafari) 
{    
window.location.href = appUrl;
var startTime = new Date();
setTimeout(function() 
{                
    if (new Date() - startTime < 600) 
    {                 
        if (window.location.href != webUrl) 
            window.location.href = webUrl;
    }
}, 500);
}
```

Comment: make use of callbacks instead of setTimeout. Once determine the condition of where to redirect then call this callback function.

Comment: please give me some example of this related script...

Comment: how do you find out if the user has the app or not?

Comment: Detect via user agent, passing app url (scheme) also finding app

Comment: So I didn't understand the need of setTimeout....based on the user agent you already know whether he is using an app or the browser.